# Wordwrap in Kile?

Tags: kile, ide

I can't seem to wrap my words to the size of the window in the IDE Kile. This results in my line of LaTeX being very long and ridiculous and the kile window scrolling to the right.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Settings --> Configure Kile, look under Editor --> Appearance, and check "Dynamic word wrap".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The F10 key toggles Word Wrap off and on in Kile.

Comment: Just to add that if you want to turn word wrap on just once (rather than every time you start Kile), you can also select it in the View menu.